# Leaderboard setup for Android

Tags: unity, google-play-services, google-play

I am totally new for this setup. I am trying to implement google Leaderboard. I followed the step by step process showed in ["This Link"](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). i opened windows -> Google play games -> setup -> Android setup. In Android setup i named the class name and copy and paste the xml code from play store account

This Picture Shows this[image]

then i  clicked setup button. i got two popup boxes, Shows below,

[image: First popup Box]
[image: Second popup Box]

in console i got messages
[image: first message]
[image: Second message]

Note: All my software's are updated version only. first i used jdk 64bit. now i uninstalled 64bit and i installed jdk 32 bit. still i got the same problem

[image]

Anybody Please help.

Edit 2:
   using [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnIkVKSed4I) now i fixed the error JAVA_HOME not set.

then in unity i tried to do the same. Now it displays another message shown below[image]

Comment: You have `JDK_HOME` set, but not `JAVA_HOME`. Also is there any reason your `JDK_HOME` points to a folder containing `jre` rather than `jdk`?

Comment: @Mario thanks for your reply. No, there is no reson, I just tried on both jdk and jre thats the only reason. Now i created an another variable JAVA_HOME. but still its not working.